# Manga where MC dies due to gods mistake and is brought back to life in Japan

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for a manga where the Main Character (MC) dies due to god's mistake and the god revives the MC in his own body. The MC died but was brought back to life in his original body, but with added on cheat abilities as an apology from the god. I don't remember the mistake but the god looked like mister Miyagi, bald medium length beard and with glasses in Japanese style clothing.

The MC saves a black cat, who is a lion spirit. He then starts to help his female classmate who is some sort of exorcist. The black cat (a lion with some sort of like tattoos in its spirit form) was like the guardian god of the classmate's (a girl with long black hair) clan it can also speak to the MC, the cat also teaches the mc on how to make a bird familiar out of paper

The MC fights for their clan in a tournament among exorcist clans, where he wears a mask in order to hide his identity. During the clan tournament he fights along side the classmate and her younger sister in a 3v3.

In the last chapter I remember reading he went to save his two kouhai, a girl and a boy, they were being targeted by an extremist clan that wanted to get rid of loose ends, so they sent two of their agents after them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the mistake and revival? The main character dies, so god reincarnates him - in the same body, same world? So it's just like nothing happened at all?

Comment: I dont remember the mistake but the god looked like mister miyagi, bald medium length beard and with glasses in japanese style clothing, i do remember that the black cat(lion with some sort of like tattoos in its spirit form) was like the guardian god of the classmates(girl with long black hair) clan it can also speak to the mc, the cat also teaches the mc on how to make a bird familiar out of paper, during the clan tournament he fights along side the classmate and her younger sister in a 3v3

Comment: the mc died but was brought back to life in his original body he just had added on cheat abilities as an apology from the god

Comment: and yes in his original world right back in japan, last chapter i remember reading he went to save his two kouhai and girl and a boy, they were being targeted by an extremist clan that wanted to get rid of loose ends, so they sent two of their agents after them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *[Isekai Tensei... Saretenee](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-tensei-saretenee)*.

> On the first day of high school, Yuuki Kousuke was killed while trying to help someone. However, that was not the end of his story. **The old man he helped happened to be a god**. As thanks, he lets Kousuke reincarnate into another world. He was overjoyed to live the life of those overpowered protagonists seen in his favorite isekai stories, however, when he came to, he found himself at the very same spot he died. This is the story of a protagonist living a peaceful life in the modern era with the cheat ability given to him by a god... not. **The cat he ended up saving turned out to be a god too.**

The story opens with the main character finding an old man stumbling in front of a railroad crossing; he rushes out to help him, and finds himself in a white room with the old man declaring himself to be god.

[image: The old man god]

The god offers to reincarnate him in another world, but ends up reviving his original body instead. The synopsis is actually wrong; he wakes up in the morgue, naked, not "at the same spot he died". Without telling him, he also grants Kousuke cheat abilities, which leads to him beating up a bunch of thugs that were threatening a girl, and lets him see his classmate's shikigami.

It hasn't been revealed to Kousuke, but one of his classmates is an onmyouji and is suspicious of him.

[image: Classmate and her younger sister]

Towards the end of the first chapter, he saves a cat with unusual markings that can talk. Later on it transforms into a larger form that looks like a lion with tattoos.

[image: Cat God]

I can't confirm the tournament, but with all the other matching details, this has to be it.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Revival` and `Onmyouji`.

Comment: You are a F-ING LEGEND!!!!!

Comment: @zeus You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).